# Update multiple row in table take one column data and update into next column in plsq

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having table column

ID Fname1 fname2 three columns. I want to update fname1 data to fname2 column.

i try this

```
update test1 set lname = (select replace(fname,'.txt') from test1);
```

but it only sut for one column if i give whare condation id=1 like that it working.
but i need to update all row like this.

Comment: Can't you use  - update test1 set lname =replace(fname,'.txt') ?

Comment: i try this it working for where id=1 like one row

Answer (score 0):

```
update test1 set lname = replace(fname,'.txt');
```